Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:3.3.0:run (default-cli)
I’m encountering an issue while trying to run my Spring Boot application with mvn spring-boot:run and I am receiving the following error:
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:3.3.0:run (default-cli) on project test2: Process terminated with exit code: 1 -> [Help 1]

When I run the command mvn spring-boot:run -e it gives me this explanation:
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Process terminated with exit code: 1
    at org.springframework.boot.maven.JavaProcessExecutor.run (JavaProcessExecutor.java:74)
    at org.springframework.boot.maven.RunMojo.run (RunMojo.java:76)
    at org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo.run (AbstractRunMojo.java:251)


You will need to add which profile you want your application to start with. Assuming you have multiple profiles. Something like: mvn spring-boot:run -Dspring-boot.run.profiles=local check it out and let me know. I can add an answer for you then.

Please share more of Maven's log output. Your application has failed to start but we cannot tell why as you haven't shared the failure.

Hey @AndyWilkinson when not providing the profile to start the application through maven, that is the only log that shows and it is on maven side. The application itself will not log anything unless set to trace.

@JorgeCampos do you work with @RimDammak? Generally speaking, there's no need for a Spring Boot application to be started with a particular profile so, unless you work with them, I don't understand how you'd know about the need for a profile. If you do work with them, perhaps you can help them to add some further information to the question. As I said in my earlier comment, it's currently impossible to tell why the application won't start.

@AndyWilkinson I do not work with them. Reason I suggested it is because I do work with dozens of microservices and everytime we start one with maven without specifying a profile, that happens.

It also depends on whether there are multiple profiles set and specific configuration depending on the profiles.

@JorgeCampos that must be specific to something what you're doing. With Boot's default configuration, you can start an app using mvn spring-boot:run and no profiles just fine.

@AndyWilkinson Yes that is correct, because of my configuration I had the same fail OP is experience hence my suggestion to try adding their profile to the command. Maybe my original comment should have been: "You should try to add" instead "You will need to add"
